# How I can use object in string interpolation in angular directive (i.e ng-init)r?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a function which creates angular element and append to container through jquery. I want to use ng-init. Following in my code.

```
 _createItem = function (chart) {

        let item = angular.element(
          `<div class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-init="chart = ${chart}">


        </div>`);

        $compile(item)($scope);
        $(".grid").append(item);

      }
```

Using above code app generates syntax error.

Comment: What error does your code lead to? What is the `chart` object passed into `_createItem` function? What is its structure? Please, provide more details

Comment: Error: Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 17 of the expression [chart = [object Object]] starting at [Object]]

chart is an object that will use in child level e.g 
`<div class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-init="chart = ${chart}">
<h2 class="title">{{chart.title}}</h2>
</div>`

_createItem creates items and notify gridifier (js library for gird layout) that a new item is appended in container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains two problems. First of them is how you do string interpolation. Since `chart` is an object, string interpolation mechanism would call its `toString` method while doing its job, so you would get `<div class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-init="chart = [object Object]"></div>` (with line breaks) instead of what you expect. Moreover, in such a case `ng-init` content is not a valid AngularJS expression. The next problem is how you pass objects into AngularJS template. Your compiled template is bound to a particular scope, so it would have an access to scope-level object only. Paying attention to the problem mentioned by you in the comment under the answer, I would suggest to create separate scope for each of charts. So, you have to change your code as follows:

```
_createItems = function () {
        const itemsData = $scope.$ctrl.chartList;
        for (let i = 0; i < itemsData.length; i++) {
             let chart = itemsData[i];
             _createItem(chart);
        }
}

_createItem = function (chart) {
        let newScope = $scope.$new(true); // if you need to inherit $scope properties, pass false here
        newScope.chart = chart;

        let item = angular.element(
          `<div class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-init="chart = chart">


        </div>`);

        $compile(item)(newScope);
        $(".grid").append(item);

      }
```

Finally, I think `ng-init` does not make sense in this particular example, as `chart` is already defined in `newScope`.

Comment: In my case I am using for loop to create new item as follow.
`_createItems = function () {
            const itemsData = $scope.$ctrl.chartList
            for (let i = 0; i < itemsData.length; i++) {
              let chart = itemsData[i];
              _createItem(chart);
            }
          }`
Instead of this I should use ng-repeat but i need to append element so that gridifier will notify about new element. If i use $scope.chart it will show the last chart item in all my grids.

Comment: Thanks alot @arcquim. You saved my day.